# Deserialize MimeMessages JavaMail

Tags: java, serialization, jakarta-mail, mime-message

Good afternoon in my timezone.

I am working with JavaMail api with exJello Provider. I am using SearchTerm class to filter the retrieved messages but it takes in average more than 1 minute to the search method returns results.So i decided to serialize a set of messages this way i did not have to wait so long.so i have one theoretical issue and one specif issue.
1) Only the classes that implements the Serializable interface could be serialize so the way i use to "serialize" this messages is not  a "really" serialization, right ?
 Snippet of my code : message.writeTo("OutputStream");

2) Now the problem that i am dealing with:
  Snippet of code:

```
  messages = inbox.search(new AndTerm(terms));
  ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(new  FileOutputStream("serializer.txt"));
   for(Message msg : messages){
      msg.writeTo(stream);
    }
```

In the end of the process i had serialize more than one message in the file "serializer.txt". My question is how can i deserialize those messages.I already am able to deserialize one messeage , but if the file contains more than one message only the first one get deserialize.
Code:

```
ObjectInputStream file = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("serializer.txt"));
new MimeMessage(session,file);
```

This code will deserialize just one message , but if i make a cicle only the first one will be again deserialize. So any body had face the same issue.
PS-> If i try to use the method readObject from any InputStream it will retrieve an exception, the only way is to use the Message constructor.

With the best regards

Comment: You should first look at how to use Java Serialization Api properly. You are not going through basic concepts and wasting time for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [ObjectInputStream.readObject()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject%28%29)

```
ObjectInputStream messages= new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("serializer.txt"));
while(messages.available()){
   MimeMessage message = (MimeMessage)messages.readObject()
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either serilizable or externalizable interface for serialization . Serializable is a marker interface and java will do the serialization for you . If you use externalizable  you can write your own serialization method .

If we go according to the definition of serialization then what you are doing can be termed serialization . Coz you are writing your object to a file and are able to restore from it.

> In computer science, in the context of data storage and transmission, serialization is the process of converting a data structure or object state into a format that can be stored (for example, in a file or memory buffer, or transmitted across a network connection link) and "resurrected" later in the same or another computer environment.

For the next part :: do not write all serialized objects in the same file . Create a file dynamically for each serialized object. Use a naming structure for identifying the correct file you want to desirialize and that will solve your problem